# Building my first operating system

Tags: operating-system

I am a programmer with a good knowledge on Java, C, C++ and Ruby.

I know just got an idea of building an operating system, so I bought an empty hard disk and I connected to my SATA cable removing it from my old hard disk. I am somewhat aware of assembly language.

Now my problem is how to start my first program on the hard disk just like adding two numbers or something. Previously, I used micro processor kit to write my assembly level programs (also used MASAMS software).

Will you please let me know for the bare system without any kernel only by having some boot startup program in motherboard how to write programs?

Comment: Interesting! I think writing an operating system could be very educative.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest starting with a virtualization approach though, it will be much easier to debug and build for.

Once you have something a little more stable you can try it out on actual hardware.

Apart from reading up on the topic (I suggest buying a book or two), maybe you can start by looking at existing projects such as [GeekOS](http://geekos.sourceforge.net/) for inspiration.

Good luck with your venture!

Comment: Definitely virtualise; it makes the compile/run/debug cycle a lot more sane.

Comment: thank you, can you link me to best resource for starting the things through virtuvalization

Comment: The GeekOS project say they use [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/). I also know of [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is to write a boot sector program. [This](http://kos.enix.org/pub/bootwrit.html) should help you. Also note you won't have any of the OS's facilities for printing to the screen so you will need to use the BIOS functions. I recommend you use a VM first instead until you get it right before trying to do it on an actual hard drive. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you its a good suggestion to me....

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to start from [MikeOS](http://mikeos.berlios.de/write-your-own-os.html) . It has preliminary introduction to assembly programming and all the tools you need to start your own OS ( including assembler, pc emulator, etc ), and also a very simple operating system which helps you to dive in .
After that, when got familiar with basics, you may want to take a look at [OSDev](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/index) for much more serious stuff . There a lot's of tutorial in there that you can make use of.